# Insert HTML with Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, actionlink

I am new with MVC. But instead of using jQuery I want to use `Ajax.ActionLink` to call an `Action` that returns a `View`. 

But when I am using `ActionLink` like below it inserts the whole body content into the `UpdateTargetId`:

```
        @Ajax.ActionLink("Projects", "Index", "Project", new AjaxOptions
       {
           LoadingElementId = "ajax-loader",
           UpdateTargetId = "content",
           InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
       })
```

I want only specific element to be inserted into the target id e.g.`table`. I can easily do that using `jQuery.load` and selector `table`. But is there anyway to do the same thing using `ActionLink`?

Comment: what does the action link return. you might want to return a partial view rather than a view maybe?

Comment: It is currently returning a full View. But is there anyway I can specify with selectors in the ActionLink initialization to insert only matching selectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Adween was right. I had to return a Partial View.